# Regular expression to exclude string from match

Tags: regex, url-rewriting

I am writing regex pattern for nginx rewrite rules to redirect the url. Here is string pattern which I would like to match and not-match.

Match url for below uri.

```
/abc/def  
/abc/def/#  
/abc/def#/  
/abc/def/#/
```

Exclude the url if `test` in the string.

```
/abc/def/test  
/abc/def#/test  
/abc/def/#/test  
/abc/def/test/dsadasd  
/abc/def#/test/dadsd
```

I have written below regex pattern but it is failing for two match highlighted in yellow

[image]

Any suggestions to fix this? Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this regex pattern:

```regex
^\/abc\/def(?!.*\btest\b).*$
```

### Demo

This regex asserts that `test` as a component does not appear anywhere in the path after the first two components.  You could also match for `\btest\b`, and reject any such matches.